# How to make div size to contents as screen size shrinks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a div with class of row, and in it 4 col-md-3 divs, however when the screen size shrinks to the breakpoint at which the divs align under each other I want the parent div to also resize. How can I do this?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">text</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">text</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">text</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a custom class to the parent div, setting out how you want it to behave `<div class="row resizer">`. You will need to write the new rule into your CSS, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use class **row-fluid** instead of **row**.

Answer (score 1):

Add you setting for xs sm too

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3  col-xs-3">text</div>
   <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3  col-xs-3">text</div>
   <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3  col-xs-3">text</div>
   <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3  col-xs-3">text</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">text</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">text</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">text</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">text</div>
</div>
```